# Regular expression to replace first underscore with comma

Tags: regex, vim

I have this pattern

```
a,abc_def_eghi
1,234_556
5,567_987_ghi
```

I want to replace the first `_` with a `,`. I know `%s/old/new/g` to replace contents in Vim.

Result

```
a,abc,def_eghi
1,234,556
5,567,987_ghi
```

Could you suggest some alternatives to go about it

Answer (score 8):

The `g` is for "global".  If you leave it off, the substitution will apply only once on each line.

```
%s/old/new/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to replace the *first* occurrence of a match, do not use the `g` modifier. That is, use `s/old/new/` instead of `s/old/new/g`. More vim search/replace tips and tricks can be found over at [Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).